# Montar SQL para gerar um dataset e popular um Treeview

Tags: sql, sql-select, mysql

Estou com um banco de dados aqui e estou querendo montar um SQL para gerar um dataset em Delphi e depois popular um Treeview. A figura abaixo mostra parte do banco, mas que é a estrutura geral do mesmo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente o usuário loga no sistema (tbuser) gerando uma tupla na tabela tbuser_logger, a qual pega o id do usuário, ele então cria um projeto na tabela tbprojeto e depois gera uma tupla na tabela tbdataid, que vai o id do projeto e o usuário logado. Depois disso cada outra tabela que o usuário gravar um dado como as tabelas tbcliente, tbcasa, tbcarro, tbam, o id gerado da tupla gerada anteriormente na tabela tbdataid será gravado, assim eu poderei saber qual o projeto que aquele dado foi gravado e qual o usuário que estava logando quando aquele dado foi criado. Dessa forma eu posso depois filtrar por exemplo os dados da tabela tbcasa pelo projeto que está sendo utilizado naquele momento. Estou montando um SQL da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT t1.datId,t2.instNome,t3.cltNome,t6.docNome                                                   
FROM tbdataid t1                                                        
INNER JOIN tbinstituicao t2 ON (t1.datId = t2.instDat_Id)           
INNER JOIN tbcliente t3 ON (t1.datId = t2.instDat_Id)
INNER JOIN tbdocumento t6 ON (t1.datId = t6.docDat_Id)  
INNER JOIN tbuser_logger t4 ON (t1.datUsrLog_Id = t4.usrLogId)      
INNER JOIN tbuser t5 ON (t4.usr_Id = t5.usrId)
WHERE t1.datProj_Id = 12 #onde o id do projeto é 12
```

No exemplo acima eu coloquei apenas 3 tabelas, mas não traz nenhum dado, se usar o left join, traz um consulta meia louca. Como eu poderia montar essa consulta pra essa estrutura de tabelas e posteriormente eu puder montar o Treeview (que é mais fácil)?

**EDIÇÃO**

Consegui montar a consulta com a ajuda a baixo, ficou assim:

```
SELECT 
    t1.datId,t2.projNome 'Projeto',t6.usrLogin 'Usuário',t3.instNome 'Instituições',
    t4.cltNome 'Clientes',t7.atvNome 'Atividades',t8.atvGrpNome 'Grupos de Atividades',
    t9.locNome 'Locais', t11.locTipNome 'Tipos de Locais',t12.medNome 'Estações de Medição'
FROM 
    tbdataid t1
    LEFT JOIN tbprojeto t2 ON (t1.datId = t2.projDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tbinstituicao t3 ON (t1.datId = t3.instDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tbcliente t4 ON (t1.datId = t4.cltDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tbativ t7 ON (t1.datId = t7.atvDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tbativgrupo t8 ON (t1.datId = t8.atvGrpDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tblocal t9 ON (t1.datId = t9.locDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tblocalativ t10 ON (t1.datId = t10.locAtvDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tblocal_tipo t11 ON (t1.datId = t11.locTipDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tbmed t12 ON (t1.datId = t12.medDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tbmedvar t13 ON (t1.datId = t13.medVarDat_Id)
    LEFT JOIN tbuser_logger t5 ON (t1.datUsrLog_Id = t5.usrLogId)
    LEFT JOIN tbuser t6 ON (t5.usr_Id = t6.usrId)  
WHERE 
    (t1.datProj_Id = 1 AND (t6.usrId = 2 AND t1.datProjCen_Id IS NULL))
    OR (t1.datProj_Id = 1 AND t1.datProjCen_Id IS NULL)
    OR (t1.datProj_Id IS NULL AND t6.usrId = 2)
```

O resultado ficou algo como a imagem abaixo e como eu queria, mais ainda traz tuplas onde tudo é NULL. O que queria saber é como posso melhorar essa query?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu cadastro varias tabelas com apenas um valor de dataid minha consulta traz algo como a imagem abaixo, mesmo meu banco sendo muito pequeno.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Bem primeiro vamos a query:

Você parte de tbDataId e faz um join com tbProjeto. TbDatId possui um ou mais projetos e um tbProjeto pertence a um e a somente um tbDataId. Então de acordo com seu modelo sua query começaria assim:

```
select * from tbDataId inner join tbProjeto on tbDataId.dataId = tbProjeto.projData_Id
```

Depois você vai para instituição, clientes e documento, cujo relacionamento eu não sei. Se poder compartilhar esses relacionamentos na sua pergunta seria top.

Enfim, então sua query fica assim:

```
select * 
from tbDataId 
inner join tbProjeto on tbDataId.dataId = tbProjeto.projData_Id
left join tbInstituicao on (tbDataId.datId = tbInstituicao.instDat_Id)
left join tbCliente on (tbDataId.datId = tbCliente.cltDat_Id)
```

Finalmente você vai até o usuário. No seu modelo todo tbDataId possui um e somente um tbUserLogger e todo tbUserLogger possui um ou vários tbDataId. Analogamente tbUser.

Finalmente sua query ficaria:

```
select tbDataId.datProj_Id, tbInstituicao.instNome, tbCliente.cltNome 
from tbDataId 
inner join tbProjeto on tbDataId.dataId = tbProjeto.projData_Id
left join tbInstituicao on (tbDataId.datId = tbInstituicao.instDat_Id)
left join tbCliente on (tbDataId.datId = tbCliente.cltDat_Id)
inner join tbuser_logger ON (tbDataId.datUsrLog_Id = tbuser_logger .usrLogId)      
inner join tbuser ON (tbuser_logger .usr_Id = tbuser .usrId)
```

Aparentemente esta consulta agora está correta.

Comment: @Artur_Indio Editei um pouco minha resposta.

Comment: A consulta está certa ela tem que retornar isso mesmo, talvez vc não esteja entendendo a estrutura das tabelas, eu queria só saber se tinha como remover as tuplas null pra facilitar a criação do treeview

Comment: Ahhhhhh, entendi. Tem que explicar direito mano! Deixa eu olhar direito que eu já já edito.

Comment: @Artur_Indio Veja se ajuda agora cara pálida.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlink dei outra edição explicando o processo de gravação da minha tabela.

Comment: Tem como remover essas tuplas todas `null` por exemplo?

Comment: Sim, basta botar no where.

Comment: dá uma olhada no resultado da query quando tenho apenas um valor de dataid, no exemplo 1, para varias tabelas.